# closing http session from other thread

Tags: web-applications, servlets, spring-mvc, session-state, httpsession

I've implemented a Web application using Spring MVC. The Web application is integrated in a system that has a desktop user interface. I would like to allow users to close Web application's sessions from the destkop GUI.

I tried implementing a non very elegant solution: invoke httpsession's invalidate but it breaks sometimes when the session being invalidated is used within a running http request. It throws an IllegalStateException at DispatcherServlet when it is trying to invoke render (specifically at WebUtil.getSessionAttribute) because it is trying to access a session attribute and the session is already invalid.

So my question is: is there any way to kick a user from its session from a non-http-request thread without having conflicts with running http requests? Or at least a conflict that I can manage.

Thanks,

Jorge

Comment: hmm i know that you can get some Session information via JMX in e.g. Apache Tomcat. You could check your application server/servlet container with a JMX console. If there's the possibility to end sessions, you can use the JMX API programatically.

Comment: Thanks @fas. I'll have a look at JMX API. Anyway, I would like to use it independently of the Web application server. So let's see if anyone knows other options too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hand-roll a mechanism involving a static set of sessions that you want to expire, and a servlet filter that checks this set for the current session, then calls `session.invalidate` and redirects the user cleanly. Your desktop API would simply add a session to this set, and the user would become invalidated cleanly (in an HTTP request thread) upon the following request.

In order to prevent memory leaks, you would also need a listener to remove a session from this set upon invalidation- thus ensuring that this set only contains valid sessions.